# how to call json object on popup?

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I am trying to call the json object on pop-up but unable to make it happen....!
please suggest me if i am wrong somewhere.
My html file is here:

```
<html>

<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function advanceSearch() {
      $("#test").dialog({

        width: '90%',
        modal: true
      });
    }

    function getInformation() {
      alert("hello");
      $.ajax({
        url: "/response.json",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response) {
          alert("hello2");
          $.each(response.BankAccounts, function(item) {
            informationArray.push(item);
            alert(data[0].bank)
          });
          informationArray.push("success");
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="BankAccounts" name="BankAccounts">
    Sort Code :
    <input type="text" name="sortCode1" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="sortCode2" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="sortCode3" />
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="search" value="Search" onclick="getInformation()"> Bank Name :
    <input type="text" name="bank" />
    <br> Branch Name :
    <input type="text" name="branch" />
    <br>
  </form>
  <div id="test" style="display: none;">
    This is a sample content
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and my json is here:

```
{
  "BankAccounts": [{
      "bank": "HSBC"
      "branch": "nlbc road"
    }, {
      "bank": "BOA"
      "branch": "New York"
    }

  ]
}
```

on click i want to call the bank-name on popup

Comment: What do you mean by _"call"_ a Json object?

Comment: Your json file is not valid.

Comment: No `$(document).ready(function(){})` no jQuery

Comment: You need to delineate object properties with a comma in JSON, try using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Daniel_L Can you please show me an example? As i am new in it

Comment: @Akash you can copy and paste your JSON code and the site will automatically tell you where it needs to be corrected